# Determining linearized polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials, coding-theory

I'm studying [this article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0703061.pdf), and I have related to the proof of theorem 14.

Let $f$ be a linearized polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_{q^m}$, which means $f$ is of the form
$$
f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} a_0 x^{q^i},
$$
where $a_i\in \mathbb{F}_{q^m}$. In the proof I need to find two linearized polynomials $f$ and $g$ of degree at most $q^{k-1}$ such that $f$ and $g$ are equal on $k-1$ linearly independent points, i.e. $f(\alpha_i)=g(\alpha_i)$ for $i=1,...,k-1$, where the $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_{k-1}$ are linearly independent points.

My idea so far is to consider the vectorspace $V=\left<\alpha_1,...,\alpha_{k-1}\right>$ and define $f(x)=\prod_{\beta\in V}(x-\beta)$. And then define $g(x)=c\cdot f(x)$, where $c\neq1$ is some non-zero scalar in $\mathbb{F}_q$. Clearly $f(\alpha_i)=g(\alpha_i)$ for all $i$, since $\alpha_i$ are roots. This does unfortunately not work if $q=2$ because the only scalar to choose from is $1$. Does anyone have an idea how to remedy this?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: I may have misunderstood, but it sounded to me like in their proof of Theorem 14 the authors say that if $f$ and $g$ were two such polynomials, then they would be equal. That is the content of their Lemma 11. In other words, I don't understand why you would want to find those two linearized polynomials?